# Angular - show loading while performing front end tasks

Tags: angular, loading, jstree

I have a jstree. I need to iterate through all nodes and display/hide nodes based on selected filter. While doing so, I want to display a loading symbol until the iteration is complete.

Displaying loading while calling an API works fine. But for front end tasks this approach does not work

test.html:

```
<div *ngIf="filterLoading" class="loading-dots loading-dots--dark">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!filterLoading">
    <button (click)="filterTree(0)">Active</button>
    <button (click)="filterTree(1)">Inactive</button>
</div>
```

test.component.ts:

```
...
export class Test implements OnInit{
...
filterLoading:Boolean = false;

filterTree(filterIdx: Number){
    this.filterLoading = true;

    var nodes = $('#jstree').jstree(true).get_json('#', { flat: true });
    if(filterIdx == 0){
        if(node["status"] == "inactive"){
            $("#jstree").jstree(true).hide_node(node);
        }else{
            $("#jstree").jstree(true).show_node(node);
        
         }
    }

    this.filterLoading = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, and your component check changes on events, like HTTP calls. When you do it inside code without events, you have to trigger change detection manually for refresh view.

Just inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and trigger change detection on any changes, like this:

```
this.filterLoading = true;
this.cdRef.detectChanges();

...

this.filterLoading = false;
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Not sure if we are missing anything. This did not work

Comment: " $('#jstree').jstree(true).get_json('#', { flat: true }); is not a function() " is the error I got.